# Including scss files in ruby on rails for each view

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am developing an application in Ruby on Rails. 
`view/layouts/application.html.erb` contains the basic layout of the file
`view/sessions/new.html.erb` contains logic related to session. application.html.erb yields to this page.

Now I have used some css styling in my new.html.erb file. I have added the corresponding CSS in in `assets/stylesheets/sessions.scss`

In my `application.html.erb` file I have included the css file this way:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "sessions.scss" %>
```

However when I look at the source code of the html file generated it shows: `sessions.scss.css` and it is not able to load the file.

What is the correct procedure?

Comment: I think your file naming may be off.  Try renaming the file `sessions.css.scss` or `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "sessions" %>`

Comment: If  I use <%= stylesheet_link_tag "sessions" %> it will take sessions.css and that file doesnt exist!

Comment: Also it looks like it is retrieving the file from http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/sessions.scss.css  -->shouldnt it point to assets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( sessions.css )
```

in my  `assets.rb`  file in `config/initializers`